# Solución a las validaciones de devise al actualizar usuarios desde un admin Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Acabo de solucionar un problema que consistía en que, al momento de querer actualizar un registro de usuario desde el admin, requería la contraseña y contraseña de confirmación, cuando sólo debería de pedirlas al momento de actualizar.

Afortunadamente logré solucionarlo mediante este enlace de la wiki de devise: *[How To: Manage users through a CRUD interface](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3A-Manage-users-through-a-CRUD-interface)*

Tengo ciertas dudas sobre esto:

1. Por qué pide agregar un prefijo, me refiero a que ¿esto afectará en algo el enrutamiento de edición de devise?
2. Sugiere el uso de un scope "/admin". En mi caso, he creado un controller llamado "admin" y dentro de ella he creado un archivo llamado "dashboard". ¿De qué manera sería enrutada la segunda opción en mi caso?
3. Ya que esto ha afectado mi enrutamiento de devise, ¿de qué forma podría solucionarlo?

Answer (score 1):

> 1. Porque pide agregar un prefijo, me refiero a que ¿esto afectara en algo el enrutamiento de edición de devise?

Para ver como afecta tu enrutamiento puedes ocupar el comando `rails routes` antes y después de agregar la sentencia que quieres ver como cambia.

> 2. Sugiere el uso de un scope "/admin", en mi caso en creado un controller llamado "admin" y dentro de ella he creado un archivo llamado "dashboard", de que manera seria enrutada la segunda opción en mi caso?

El scope `"/admin"` es una sugerencia que te hacen, si ya tienes un modelo `Admin` y sus respectivos metodos, rutas y todo, es mejor que cambies el socpe  uno que te acomode más ( "/superuser" , "/a" , .... )